# Retornando dados selecionados para Razor em objeto anônimo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo um controller onde busco os aniversariantes do mês. Porém possuo mais de 1000 aniversariantes por mês, retornando uma tabela com mais de 50  atributos de cada um, tonando assim a consulta demorada.

```
    public ActionResult Aniversariantes()
    {
        var usuarios = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.DtNascimento.Month == DateTime.Now.Month);
        var usuariosOrdenados = usuarios.OrderBy(u => u.DtNascimento.Day)ToList();
        return View(usuariosOrdenados);
    }
```

Para tentar resolver, tentei buscar apenas os campos que desejo mostrar em minha View.

```
public ActionResult Aniversariantes()
    {
        var usuarios = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.DtNascimento.Month == DateTime.Now.Month);
        var usuariosOrdenados = usuarios.OrderBy(u => u.DtNascimento.Day).Select(x => new{x.DtNascimento, x.NmFuncionario, x.Descricao}).ToList();
        return View(usuariosOrdenados);
    }
```

Porém deste jeito recebo o seguinte erro ao acessar a View:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.DateTime,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario]'.

Rastreamento de pilha

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.DateTime,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary.set_Model(Object value) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +614
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1..ctor(ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.set_ViewData(ViewDataDictionary value) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +425
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9715856
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Aniversariantes do Mês";
}




<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
        $j("#myTable").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            dataSource: { pageSize: 15 }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="Nome">
    <p><strong><font face="Arial" size="2"> @ViewBag.Matricula / @ViewBag.Contrato - @ViewBag.Nome</font></strong></p>
</div>
<div class="mapLocal">
    <img src="~/Content/img/sitemap.ico" width="19" height="19" /> Você está em: <i>@ViewBag.Title</i>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5><strong>Aniversariantes do Mês</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome do Funcionário</th>
                        <th>Secretaria</th>
                        <th>Data do Aniversário</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.NmFuncionario
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.Descricao
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.DtNascimento.Day.ToString("00")/ @item.DtNascimento.Month.ToString("00")
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dúvida: Como retornar apenas os três campos que realmente necessito na consulta?

Lembrando que a forma que estou fazendo, ao debugar o código eu recebo o resultado correto, apenas os três campos. Porém ao listar na View recebo este erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas formas:

## A forma recomendada

Crie um `ViewModel` tipado com os 3 campos que você precisa. Passe para o Razor uma coleção tipada:

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.ViewModels.UsuarioViewModel>
```

## A forma não recomendada

Funciona, mas tende a criar o caos. Faça o Razor aceitar um objeto dinâmico:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Não é recomendado porque todos os campos são resolvidos em tempo de execução, o que dificulta na prevenção de erros.

Comment: Ao criar a **ViewModel** eu necessito realizar alguma alteração em meu Controller?

Comment: Na primeira forma, o Select ficaria assim: `.Select(x => new UsuarioViewModel {x.DtNascimento, x.NmFuncionario, x.Descricao}`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema.
Porém da forma que colocou recebo erro de sintaxe, ai alterei um pouquinho o código, ficando assim: **.Select(x => new UsuarioViewModel ()
            {
                Descricao = x.Descricao, NmFuncionario = x.NmFuncionario, DtNascimento = x.DtNascimento
            }).ToList();**

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Exatamente isso.